# PHP: call to undefined utf8_decode fatal error while using PHP 7.2

Tags: php

I wonder if you can help me solve the error "PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function utf8_decode() in /var/www/andreamorouk/public_html/test.php:65 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in xxxx" on my Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS instance using PHP 7.2.

I've an ubuntu machine, where I have also installed the php7.0-xmlrpc package.

The issue is when I try to call the function from within a script. That's when I get the fatal error.
However, strangely when - via shell - I run a php -r 'echo utf8_decode('something');' everything works fine.

my list of active modules in php (via php -m) looks like so:

```
apcu
calendar
Core
ctype
date
dom
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mbstring
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
sockets
sodium
SPL
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
xsl
Zend OPcache
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Zend OPcache
```

Perhaps few more than I need? In fact, I am not even sure who or what has installed them. I guess these are the default ones.

I would tend to exclude the need to activate the module or something similar, I'm not sure at this stage what the root cause of the problem is.

UPDATE 2021/03/01

A PHP_info ran from command line can be seen [here](https://pastebin.com/raw/qNwsi5HR).

Any idea?

Comment: Could you please send your php version? from php7.2, the utf8_decode is included in core, so no more modules are needed. Also please add the output that you get by running `php --ini` which will list all the ini file loaded for PHP. Could you please also past the exact error message you're seeing?

Comment: What I can guess from the details you've provided is, your php cli and the php that's running from the webserver probably do not have same config. There are separate `.ini` files for php-cli and normal php. are you running php-fpm?

Comment: I will add the details tomorrow, but yes it's PHP 7.2. When I looked for something specific for the phpxml module, I couldn't find anything, but since now the module is in the core I clearly need to look for something different.

Comment: php 7.2 has the function added to it's core. so when you paste your error, may be we'll be able to get more details.

Comment: Also, is there any chance you probably have multiple php version installed on your ubuntu? if it is, and you've php-fpm installed, probably check the socket that has been referred in your virtual host config?

Comment: No multiple version as far as I can tell, both the cli and web seens to be the same, but if you can suggests me how exactly you want me to capture, I will be doing that

Comment: @Tuhin the error in the log says this: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function utf8_decode() in /var/www/andreamorouk/public_html/test.php:65
Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in xxxx <- the script name

Comment: from the directory structure, it seems like you're on shared hosting. how are you finding details like php version, OS version etc? are you logging in from CLI?